# Is there a way to have a checkbox to show/hide, not enable/disable, functions or layout in the settings input tab?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

In Tradingviews pine code

Is there a way to have a checkbox to show/hide, not enable/disable, functions or layout in the settings input tab? What i have is a moving average with 10,21,50 periods. the layout in input tab looks like this:

fast  a box that allows you to choose the period. 10 or whatever.
mid   a box that allows you to choose the period. 21 or whatever.
slow  a box that allows you to choose the period. 50 or whatever.

This is in the settings input tab.
what i want to do is have a check box that shows/hides this layout.
I have tried bool input, but it shows/hides the indicator on the chart and not the layout.
Is there a way?
Thanks

I have tried bool input, but it shows/hides the indicator on the chart and not the layout.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. If you don't want something to be shown in the inputs section, you need to hardcode its value and not use an `input()`.